# Rails: before_destroy not updating parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my rails app, I have a `Donation model`, which has an attribute called `status` (an integer) and a child model `called Delivery`. A donation `has_one delivery`.

In the delivery model, I have callbacks

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :donation

  after_create :increment_donation_status
  before_destroy :zero_donation_status

  def increment_donation_status
    self.donation.status += 1
    self.donation.save
  end

  def zero_donation_status
    self.donation.status = 0
    self.donation.save
  end
end
```

When I create a delivery, it properly runs `increment_donation_status`, and the donation's status is incremented. However, when I destroy the delivery, the delivery gets destroyed, but the donation's status is never set back to 0.

I've tried using both `before_destroy`, and `after_destroy`. I've also tried putting a print statement in `zero_donation_status`, and it works. However, when I try to print `self.donation.id`, this does not work. For some reason, it seems as though the delivery object cannot reference its parent donation when a destroy callback is being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Even though I had a has_one relationship from donations to deliveries, the delivery I was deleting was actually pointing to a donation with two deliveries. Because of this, it couldn't resolve `self.donation`. Whoops.